# Create a border around a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a `border` around a `div` using `.wrap()` and `.unwrap()` when this `div` is clicked, but the problem is that the border appears on top of the page not around the `div`.why?

Here is my code:

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  //"main" is a tag.
  $("main").append('<div class="cards"><div class="card new" style="width: 20rem;">\
        <div class="layer"></div>\
            <div class="card-block">\
                <h4 class="card-title"></h4>\
                <p class="card-text"></p>\
            </div>\
            <div class="card-block">\
                <div class="delete">Del</div>\
                <div class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#note">edit</div>\
            </div>\
        </div></div>');
  var title = $("#noteTitle").val();
  var text = $("#noteBody").val();
  $(".new h4").html(title);
  $(".new p").html(text);
  var layer = $("#selected").css("background-color");
  $(".new .layer").css({
    "background-color": layer,
    "position": "absolute",
    "opacity": ".2",
    "top": "0",
    "left": "0",
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "100%"
  });
$(".card").removeClass("new");
});
$("main").on("click", ".card", function() {
  if ($(this).parent().is(".border")) {
    $(this).unwrap();
  } else {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="border"></div>');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="noteTitle" />
<textarea id="noteBody" ></textarea>
<button id="add">Click</button>
<main></main>
```

**CSS:**

```
.card {
margin: 10px;
height:230px;
background: url(paper.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
display: inline-block;
word-wrap: break-word;
font-family: "comic sans MS";
float: left;
padding-right: 60px;
z-index:-1;
}
.border {
border: solid 20px black;
}
```

Comment: console.log(this)... in the on('click',...) callback. is it the main-element or the card class?

Comment: You wraping around a `.border`. Lets see the `css` and is there a reason you not just adding `.css` with the `jQuery`?

Comment: It looks like you're wrapping and unwrapping the `<main>` tag

Comment: Please complete the snippet I made for you - it has errors. Fix the errors and add the CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you just put the border on the element?

Comment: Will you try using :  $(this).wrapAll('<div class="border"></div>');  which wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Your code works so....

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways to add a border than surrounding with a div... Using the CSS property border you can do it pretty easily.

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#div').css('border', '1px solid black');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Press me</button>
<div id="div">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to toggle a CSS class on the div you want a border around, not add a new div with class "border". What you're doing is appending a new div up at the top with no content, so it does not surround. And the CSS you'll want to add is something like `border: 1px solid black`

Super quick example using hover css... just modify your code to add / remove a class on click for the border piece in jQuery

http://jsbin.com/fibogojulo/edit?html,css,output